# Spyder--Web scraping

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, spyder

Am trying to scrape the data from a website, I have given the username and password but still it is throwing me the below error.

```
"URLError: urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>"
```

Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request as req

proxy = req.ProxyHandler({'http':r'http://abca:Password__@123@:192.168.115.116:8080'})    
auth = req.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()    
opener = req.build_opener(proxy, auth, req.HTTPHandler)

req.install_opener(opener)    
conn = req.urlopen('http://www.google.com')

return_str = conn.read()
```

Thanks & Regards,
Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

[URL 101](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.1):

Characters should be percent encoded when used, especially the colon and @-sign as they are part of the syntax.